# How can I type sagas in a proper way?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I followed the official docs of redux with typescript.
https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript

I was able to type actions, reducers, react components, etc.. but when I was trying to type sagas I came accross with this issue.

This is the logIn function.

```
function* logIn(action) {
  try {
    
    let email = action.payload.email;
    let password = action.payload.password;

    // Here is the code for login ////
    token = .......... login(email, password);
   

    yield put(logInSuccess(token));
 
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(logInFailed());
  }
}
```

The problem here is that I don't know how to type the action var so that I can get my email and password from payload.

What can I do in this case ?

Comment: `(action: { payload: { email: string, password: string } })`

Answer (score 1):

The action parameter here is an object with `type` property and some payload property. You can describe an interface/type for `action` that has a generic payload type.

```
interface IAction<TPayload> {
  type: string
  payload: TPayload
}
```

And then use it in your sagas like this

```
type TLoginPayload = {
  email: string
  password: string
}

function* logIn(action: IAction<TLoginPayload>) {
```

or inline

```
function* logIn(action: IAction<{ email: string; password: string }>) {
```